# Identify objects without assigned material

Tags: materials, objects

Is there a method, e.g., python script or add-on, to identify objects and/or mesh that do not have an assigned material?  Something that works with > 2.9.  There are old scripts on the internet, e.g., 2.8, but they don't work with latest blender.

Answer (score 4):

```py
import bpy

for object in bpy.data.objects:
    if object.type == 'MESH':
        found = False
        if object.material_slots:
            for slot in object.material_slots:
                if slot.material:
                    found = True
                    break
        if not found:
            print(object.name)
```

This script will print the name of any object that is a mesh but has no materials assigned.  It should work for any version of Blender since 2.8.  You can replace the `print` with whatever you want to do with the objects, of course.

If an object has no `material_slots` then obviously it has no assigned materials.  But, as pointed out in a comment, it could have `material_slots` and they could all be empty. So we look for the first material slot that has a material assigned.

Comment: This will identify an object with no material slots.  I want to identify an object whose mesh, or just a portion of its mesh, does not have an assigned material, even if there are material slots assigned.

Comment: @GLap  I've added the loop for checking existing material slots.